# Android. VK API. Получение списка пользователей

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, android-asynctask

В общем задача такая: выполнить поиск пользователей по определенным критериям и добавить их в `ArrayList`.

В начале получаю количество пользователей - `count` и передаю их в `AsyncTask` класс и там запускаю цикл который увеличивает `OFFSET_COUNT`и создает на его основе новый запрос, с уже смещенным шагом, далее выполняется метод который на основе нового запроса ищет пользователей и по определенным условиям добавляет их в список.

Во первых, метод который получает кол-во найденных пользователей срабатывает только после 2-го нажатия на кнопку или просто долго обрабатывается

Во вторых, отбор пользователей обрабатывает только ~1к из ~20к найденных.
Знаю что существует ограничение в 3 запроса в сек. к API, пробовал ставить задержку, но походу не помогает, так как после 1-2 прогонов, перестает отрабатывать даже `getCount`. Подозреваю что VK меня просто блокирует.

Как всё таки правильно запустить `execute` запроса в цикле? И если работать сразу с 1000 записями за раз, как сначала дождаться выполнения запроса к API, а потом уже начать обрабатывать инфу.

Метод получения кол-ва найденных людей:

```
Integer getCount(VKRequest vkRequest) {
    vkRequest.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            try {
                count = response.json.getJSONObject("response").getInt("count");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    return count;
}
```

Фрагмент кода выполняющийся в `doInBackground` `AsyncTask` класса

```
@Override
protected View doInBackground(VKParameters... param) {

    VKRequest request;

    int countStep = count / 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < countStep; i++) {
        OFFSET_COUNT += 50;
        param[0].put(VKApiConst.OFFSET, OFFSET_COUNT);

        try {
            TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(350);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        request = VKApi.users().search(param[0]);
        runRequest(request);
    }
    return null;
}
```

`runRequest(request)` - метод который запускает `request.executeWithListener`

Comment: Я конкретно в java не силён, но парсилка пользователей у меня работает каждый день. Если работать через api и соблюдать лимиты -- то никаких проблем не будет. Проверяйте алгоритмы, на словах вы всё правильно говорите.

Comment: Так вот бы еще знать как правильно соблюдать эти лимиты) Потому что задержка, как мне кажется, не помогает.

Comment: @Константин, почему бы не использовать разные токены?